# Rectangle coordinates after transform

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am currently drawing a rectangle with a transformation on his parent element (g). 
The resulting svg is this;

```
<svg version="1.1" width="1055" height="381">
   <g transform="rotate(120)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="10" ry="0" stroke-width="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect-0"></rect>
      <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="10" ry="0" stroke-width="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect-1"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the coordinates of one of the **rects** dynamically, but using getBBox does not return the correct result. Can anyone tell me how to get the correct x, y, width and height properties of one of the rects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution myself;

```
var matrix = shape.getCTM();

// transform a point using the transformed matrix
var position = svg.createSVGPoint();
position.x = $(shape).attr("x");
position.y = $(shape).attr("y");
position = position.matrixTransform(matrix);
```

Comment: I have been looking for like 3 days, for exactly this function, lol.  I don't know why other answers do not use it.

Comment: beware that it returns the SCREEN SPACE COORDINATE and not the actual transformed WORLD SPACE coordinates.