# How to draw a svg line from center of other element in transformed group with snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, snap.svg

I have three shapes all in the same group. This group have been transformed. I want to draw a line from one of the elements within that group. I am trying to access this elements coordinates by:

```
s.select("#hitboxHeel").getBBox().cx and s.select("#hitboxHeel").getBBox().cy
```

However this gives some weird coordinates, that are far off from where they should be. How do i get the actual position of the points, thus being able to draw a line?

Comment: Yes, when i print them, i get 514.06 and 351.61 :-)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGRect no cx or cy

Comment: Snap getBBox includes cx, cy. However, it doesn't account for transforms (unless getBBox(1) does, am unable to check just atm), so you will need to look that up and transform its x,y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found the solution from this post : [Rectangle coordinates after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858479/rectangle-coordinates-after-transform)

Here, you basically want to apply the 'aggregated' transform matrix of your shape to coordinates that are not transformed (sorry for the awkward phrasing). This matrix also incorporates the transformations of parent elements (group nodes here), so you shouldn't have to worry about them.
So, given :

- your *native* svg element **node**
- your *native* svg container **svg**
- your original point of interest coordinates (before transforms) **x** and **y** that you want transformed
- the expected transformed coordinates of your original point **transformedPoint**

`

```
// get the component transform matrix
var ctm = node.getCTM();
var svgPoint = svg.createSVGPoint(); 
svgPoint.x = x;
svgPoint.y = y;
// apply the matrix to the point
var transformedPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(ctm); 



// an example using d3.js ( svg > g > rect )
// get the center of the rectangle after tansformations occured
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 500)
    .attr('id', 'myCanvas')
    .style('margin', 100)
var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,10)')
var r = g.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 300).attr('y', 100).attr('width', 79).attr('height', 150)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-54,300)rotate(-30,30,20)')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'red')
var pt = svg.node().createSVGPoint()
pt.x = parseInt(r.attr('x')) + parseInt(r.attr('width')) / 2
pt.y = parseInt(r.attr('y')) + parseInt(r.attr('height')) / 2
var ctm = r.node().getCTM()
var center = pt.matrixTransform(ctm)
console.log('the transformed rectangle center', center)

// draw the center to confirm the accuracy of the process    
svg.append('circle') 
    .attr('cx', center.x).attr('cy', center.y).attr('r', 5)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
```

`